# What is the name of the song played for Going Merry's funeral?

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the name of the song played for Going Merry's funeral?

I have heard that is a large version of an ending but i do not know if it's true or not.

The number of the episode is 312 and also in the episode of Merry's OVA.

Comment: Can you provide an episode number and timestamp?

Comment: It is the 2nd movement of Beethoven's Symphony No. 3 *"Eroica"*, *II. Marcia funebre Adagio assai.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the song you are looking for is either '[Dear friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGIvzvMxTOA)'

One other option could be '[Mother Sea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIEzcyxM_v8)'.